# Amazon ECS Service Not Available Exception when calling RunTask from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I can run a Task on a Cluster from the AWS Console, and from the AWS CLI, but when I try and run the same task/cluster combination from Lambda I receive the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "Service Unavailable. Please try again later. (Service:     AmazonECS; Status Code: 500; Error Code: ServerException; Request ID: b02100bb-0ac4-11e7-84df-a552ac171feb)",
"errorType": "com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.ServerException",
```

I can successfully register a new Task with Lambda, and also create a new Service with a task from Lambda.

How can I get some further insight into this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one of the Task command overrides I was passing to the Task was null, which results in the obscure error: "Service Unavailable".

```
    // Task Overrides
    ContainerOverride containerOverride = new ContainerOverride();

    // Container Entrypoint Command Overrides
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    commands.add(request.getArg1());
    commands.add(request.getArg2());
    commands.add(request.getArg3()); // If any of these are null, the request fails
    commands.add(request.getArg4());
    commands.add(request.getArg5());

    containerOverride.setCommand(commands);
```